# Do we know which traits reside in which chromosome? If not, how about the next 10 years?

Tags: human-genetics, chromosome

Assuming we develop a technology that allows us to make human gametes (sperm & eggs) combining chromosomes from different persons. Thus we take 1st chromosome from 1st person, 2nd chromosome from 2nd person, 3rd from 3rd etc. Afterward we combine them and make a gamete (sperm or egg)

Do we know which traits reside in which chromosome in order to make that technology useful? If we don't know now, how about in next 10 years.

The only thing I could find is that we know which chromosome hosts genes for certain [diseases](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22266/).

P.S.
This [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/129780/do-we-know-which-traits-reside-in-which-chromosome) was originally asked on world building where it was closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know the location on the chromosomes of most of the genes in the human genome. You can go to the [UCSC](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg38&lastVirtModeType=default&lastVirtModeExtraState=&virtModeType=default&virtMode=0&nonVirtPosition=&position=chr1%3A11102837%2D11267747&hgsid=697510953_RGcSpw1aGyr2Crl5IxO78m15dDhR) or [Ensembl](https://uswest.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Location/View?r=17%3A63992802-64038237) genome browsers and look up the positions of most of the genes, and many other features of the human genome.

There may be some genes we haven't recognized yet, but the real issue with what you are asking is that biology typically isn't as simple as "one gene" = "one trait".

The simplified picture is that one gene is the recipe for one protein, but even that isn't strictly true. We now know that one gene may make several variations on a protein through a process called [splicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_splicing). Furthermore most "traits" will arise through the interactions of dozens of proteins. On top of that there is the issue of which proteins are produced when, and in which cells. Some of this is controlled by [regulatory regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulatory_sequence), and we're still very much at the beginning of [finding all the regulatory regions and how they work together](https://www.encodeproject.org).

To give you an idea of how complex this is: human height is known to be strongly heritable. We've identified about 400 regions of the human genome (genes and regulatory sequences) that have a significant effect on height. However, taken together, [the variation in human height explained by these 400 regions explains only about 20% of the observed heritable variation](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2014/10/141005134909.htm). In other words there is a great deal about the genetics of height that we simply don't understand yet.

There have been [experimental efforts to treat simple genetic diseases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_therapy) in humans by substituting or adding "healthy" versions of genes into people who have a non-functioning copy of some critical gene, but we're many decades away from creating whole gametes by cut and pasting multiple genes together. There is [considerable ethical and political opposition](https://en.unesco.org/news/unesco-panel-experts-calls-ban-editing-human-dna-avoid-unethical-tampering-hereditary-traits) to the development of such techniques.